# DC distribution

Tags: power, dc, electrical

[image]

My question is this that I am confused about the fact that we are feeding 220 V voltage from both ends of a distributor and then we are restricting that the maximum voltage should not exceed 6V what is the reason to do this?

Comment: Max.  voltage drop in "Feeder",  not the voltage across "Load".

Answer (score 1):

The problem says that the maximum **voltage drop** is 6 V, not the maximum **voltage**.

If this does not make clear what the problem is asking, then you need to study the concept of voltage drop (due to resistance in conductors) further. The textbook you are using should cover that somewhere before presenting the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is describing a ring-main topology as used in the UK for wiring within a house, where simplistically a 30A circuit is built using 15A cable. Your textbook probably describes something similar - this question is a mathematical analysis of the behaviour.

Comment: It might be similar, but the question is 220 V **DC**.

Comment: The question is about why the exercise is describing such a problem. I've given a real-world example of a similar topology. I'm not sure that DC makes a significant difference to the choice of _this aspect_ of topology (but removes some potential confusion in the analysis).